# Replacement and implementation-independence in set theory

Tags: set-theory

In his paper ‘Implementing Mathematical Objects in Set Theory’ (*Logique Et Analyse*, 2007), Thomas Forster writes

> Mathias [unpublished] has shown that if we assume that $x \times y$ exists for all $x$ and $y$ irrespective of our choice of implementation of ordered pair then the axiom scheme of replacement holds.

Similarly, Akihiro Kanamori in his ‘In Praise of Replacement’ (*BSL* 2012) says that

> Replacement can be seen as a crucial bulwark of *indifference to identification* in set theory and modern mathematics generally.

Has Matthias's proof been published? Kanamori’s essay ranges very widely: is there a crisper discussion of his particular claim about the role of Replacement as underpinning our indifference to implementation of e.g. pairs?

Comment: In Forster's remark, is "implementation of ordered pair" loosened as far as to just mean "ordered pair formation is done by any bijection $V^2\to V$ that's definable by a formula in the language of set theory"?